# Image Fourier Decomposition to save many images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, batch-processing

I wish to divide an image into 256 separate fourier layers and do some complex processing on them for an experiment and add them together again.

Can i do it in photoshop or gimp or is there a program that would batch process an image by fourier transform and save all the resulting images to disk?

Please: I am sure someone overly serious will say "this question should be on "recommend me a program forum" because it is not relevant to graphics design forum" which would clearly be dogmatic as generalists dont do that kind of image processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use **[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)** to do the Fourier transformations (see [examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fourier/)). Not only do you save yourself some time, as batch examples are plentiful and Fourier transform is built in.

You could do this in Photoshop you would just have to go and find a filter that does Fourier transform (like [here](http://www.3d4x.ch/Swift%27s-Reality/FFT-Photoshop-plugin-by-Alex-Chirokov/16,35)). The scripting interface is just a bit more verbose and in general there are less good examples to piggyback on.

Gimp is also an option but haven't done gimp scripting in ages so I wouldn't know much about this.